# Logarithmic/linear scale formula for 0.2:5mil to 10:1mil

Tags: logarithms

I'm still trying to wrap my head around logs and figuring out how to derive formulas from given value pairs.

In this example, at a value of `0.2`:`5mil` should be derived, and at `1`:`1mil` (so it's an inverse scale?).

How can I find out the output for a given value, say `0.1`?

Basically, the closer the value gets to zero, the higher the output should be.

I came across these two questions which are close to what I'm looking for but I'm still having trouble deriving these formulas.

- [Convert a linear scale to a logarithmic scale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970094/convert-a-linear-scale-to-a-logarithmic-scale)
- [Linear to semi-logarithmic scale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692583/linear-to-semi-logarithmic-scale)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 0.2:5mil?What do you mean find out the value for a given value, say 0.1?  The value is 0.1.  I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: So as I interpret this, you're essentially looking for a function $f(x)$ that has the following properties:
$$
f(0.2) = 5\cdot 10^6 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f(1) = 10^6
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = +\infty
$$
And also the function should have something to do with logarithms. If not for the logarithm part, the simplest function that fullfills these requirements is
$$
f(x) = \frac{10^6}{x}
$$ Question: should the output always be positive?

Comment: @MattiP. thanks. It looks like the linear function (10^6/x) may work. However, playing with the numbers it seems like instead of f(1), I'll need f(10) = 10^6. Can I ask how you derived the formula so I can play with different values?

Comment: @MattiP. and yes, always should be positive.

Comment: At this point it's important to decide what form you want the function to have. On one hand, you mentioned that the form $f(x) = 10^6/x$ seems fine, and that's of the more general form
$$
f(x) = Cx^{\alpha}
$$
But this has nothing to do with logarithms, which was your wish in the post. Another form that is a bit similar and has to do with logarithms, would be
$$
f(x) = Ce^{kx}
$$
So which one would you prefer? It pretty much comes down to what you want $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$ to be (finite or infinite).

Comment: @MattiP. Great question that I didn't consider before. Basically, the output is a threshold that determines whether a stock is "liquid" enough. In other words, the lower the given price, the higher the volume required to determine it "liquid" -- Given that, I assume the output should be finite, capped at 10M or so, however I would need to play with live data to see if that's the limit I want to set. Thanks for your continued help with this.